# Why is the tour page example question about unicorns?

Tags: bug, status-completed, status-bydesign

I for one am thrilled to know about the corn syrup spray solution, but wouldn't that question be a better fit on the [Gardening stack exchange?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/)

https://law.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I want to clarify, that since the most recent answer, the question on the tour page has changed to a more suitable question for the site, and is no longer about unicorns.

Answer (score 4):

The question on the tour page is a placeholder until we are able to select our own. However, it's not all that simple. There's a post on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163947/260340) with some more info. Right now, there aren't any questions that are eligible.